# selenium webdriver: how to find the text in a paragraph which is nested in a div element?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

```
<div class="loginbox">other code</div>
<div class="loginbox">
    <p> style="color: Red;">Test Extract</p>     
</div>
```

Using Selenium Web Driver, I would like to extract the text Test Extract within the paragraph element which is nested within a div, whose class name is shared with other div classes.  python please. (this is a question i found on here already, but was asking for the answer in another programming language. so i rephrased my question to suit my need for python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can simply use:

```
text = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//p[text()='Test Extract']")
print(text.text)
```

EDIT:
If you're searching for an example in other language, here's one in java:

```
WebElement text = browser.findElement(By.xpath("//p[text()='Test Extract']"));
System.out.println(text.getText());
```